# Codewars.com не принимает .В чём ошибка данного кода, решения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

**ЗАДАЧА:**

> Implement the function unique_in_order which takes as argument a
>   sequence and returns a list of items without any elements with the
>   same value next to each other and preserving the original order of
>   elements.

For example:

```
unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']

unique_in_order('ABBCcAD')         == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'c', 'A', 'D']

unique_in_order([1,2,2,3,3])       == [1,2,3]
```

**MОЙ КОД:**

```py
def unique_in_order(iterable):    
    pass   
    c=""    
    v=[]     
    for i in iterable:     
        if i!=c:     
           v.append(i)     
        c=i     
    print(v)
```

Answer (score 2):

По условию нужно вернуть список, а не вывести его в консоль:

> ... and **returns a list of items** without any elements ...

Тест:

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    c = ""
    v = []
    for i in iterable:
        if i != c:
            v.append(i)
        c = i
    return v

assert unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
assert unique_in_order('ABBCcAD')         == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'c', 'A', 'D']
assert unique_in_order([1,2,2,3,3])       == [1,2,3]
```

---

**PS.**

Этот алгоритм легко повторить через встроенный модуль `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def unique_in_order(iterable):
    return [x for x, _ in groupby(iterable)]
```